# Why doesn't createQuery() on the javax.persistence.EntityManager work with upper case attribute?

Tags: hibernate-entitymanager

I've encountered a behaviour of javax.persistence.EntityManager I'd like to understand.

I had code similar to the following:

```
 1 // Query Execution
 2 EntityManager emext;
 3 String query = "SELECT obj FROM MyDatabaseTableBE obj obj.FOO = :fooName)";
 4 Query q = emext.createQuery(query);

 5 // Corresponding BE
 6 ...
 7 public static final String FOO = "fOO";
 8 ...
 9 @AttributeMetadata(attributeNature = AttributeNature.REGULAR)
10 @SearchAttributeMetadata(searchable = false)
11 private String foo;
12 ...
13 public String getFOO() {
14    return foo;
15 }
16 ...
17 public void setFOO(final String foo) {
18    this.foo = foo
19 }
20 ...
```

throwing the following exception: **could not resolve property: fOO of: MyDatabaseTableBE** in line 4.

The only thing I changed was the capitalisation:

```
 // Corresponding BE, with changed capitalisation
...
public static final String FOO = "foo";
...
public String getFoo()
...
public void setFoo(final String fOO)
...
```

And it worked without an exception.

**Why did the first version (with the second and third character in uppercase) not work?**

Comment: Have you posted real code, it isn't compilable. FOO variable is final & static, what is the purpose of having setter method.

Comment: The final static variable ist only used to retrieve the Attribute Name "fOO". 
There's an additional variable "foo" which is not final and static, that the setter changes. I extended the example code above to show that.

Comment: @NayanWadekar, I'd like to send you the complete code via Mail if you want to have a look at it. It's a bit long for posting it all inside the question.

Comment: I would suggest you to alter the field names in more meaningful way, as they are same with change in capitalization. It will increase code readability for others. Also I will try to replicate the issue, there is some problem where fields are capitalized/decapitalized to discover setter/getter etc.